# How to import .C3D files into R?

Tags: r

Has anyone ever imported Motion Capture data from a .C3D file containing marker positions, forces, emg, etc. directly into  R?

The only way I have found so far is to open the .C3D files first using c3dserver in MatLab, saving the data I want as a .csv file and opening that file in R.

Thanks